# SQL INSERT INTO table results in duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a script that I have setup a CRON for that is getting values from a 3rd party server via JSON (cURL)

Right now every time the cron runs it will INSERT a completely new record. Causing duplicates, and resulting me in manually removing the dups.

How would I go about preventing duplicates, and only update the information that is either missing, or different from the NEW $VAR values?

What I want to do can be expressed like this: `IF old value is NOT new value use new value else use old value;`

```
    if ($stmt->num_rows !== 1) {
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                        INSERT INTO members (
                                                            start_date
                                                            )

                                        VALUES (?)")) 

        {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('s',
                                $StartDate, 

                                );

    if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) { echo ''; }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Yes. You cannot do Insert ... ON DUPLICATE key UPDATE with VALUE

Comment: @MyWay - he'd need to include the `PRIMARY KEY` (or at least a `UNIQUE` key) in the `INSERT` statement - which I'm guessing isn't the case yet,

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg lol

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

This does mean that you will have to define some *unique* (could be *primary*) key to the table that is always constant so MySQL knows what to update.

A quick example of how you would do it:

```
INSERT INTO table (f1,f2,f3) VALUES ('something_unique',2,5) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f2=2,f3=5
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. FROM ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val = VALUES(val) Taking value that will be inserted with VALUES() only works with INSERT INTO .... VALUES (...)

Comment: So I could do something like `$var = xx123` and pass that to the DB table as a dummy column/value ? Now that I think about it... This value would NOT be unique from the JSON data I am retrieving. Onlything that will be unquie really is `record` or `email` @abdrius

Comment: Well, whatever is unique (and set as one in the database) will do the trick!

Comment: @LeviZoesch - do you get the member id (`PRIMARY KEY` - presumably there is one, probably called something like `members.id` in the database) back from the JSON? If so, that's your unique data. Just try to set `members.id` in the `INSERT` statement. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will be triggered if that record already exists.

Comment: What I am saying is the values I am getting from the 3rd party server does not contain this `new` fictitious unique value. This would only be on my side, so how would the JSON coming in distinguish from the old ? the ONLY thing that I can cross reference coming INTO my DB is the `record` columns `value` is not the same... @CD001

Comment: @LeviZoesch : we're not talking about new fictitious data - simply the `PRIMARY KEY` in your database... I assume there is one right? Otherwise you're in trouble...

Comment: VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'record') Does not work @Andrius

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY is my `id` column @CD001

Comment: @LeviZoesch And you can't get that id back in the JSON?

Comment: correct. the only unquie/primary-key column value I get is from the `record` column, and I inject that into my DB.. but it creates duplicates. I've tried several things, IS NOT, NOT LIKE, UPDATE, INSERT, WHERE value=value etc, and I cannot figure it out. @CD001

Comment: ... and presumably the record is unique to the record not the *member* - so you've actually got **no** data points that can **never** change apart from the `members.id` and that doesn't come back from the JSON ... you're pretty much stuffed if that's the case, there's nothing that's unique to a given member that you can use as a definite reference point.

Comment: Wrong, the Record is unique to the MEMBER. FROM the incoming JSON @CD001

Comment: Right, I'm guessing it's not got a `UNIQUE` index defined on it in the database then?

Comment: That is Correct. The Record is unquie and the primary key for the member from JSON, but is not created on DB side. @CD001

Comment: So I'm guessing the *member* is created in your database, presumably without `members.record` data initially but when you retrieve the information from the JSON that's when you get the *record* data - at which point `members.record` is not the same as the JSON record and a new row is entered... so you've still got **no** atomic data point across both systems from start to finish - there's no way you can definitively match up the JSON to the `member` data, you need something that always exists in both systems and never changes.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will be silently ignored if one of the fields with the flags `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` already exist in the database. If you're searching for `INSERT IF NOT EXISTS` this is probably what you're looking for:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `members` SET name='Steve',start_date='2015-11-20';
```

You can also overwrite a record that already exists using `REPLACE`. If it doesn't yet exist, it will be created:

```
REPLACE INTO `members` SET name='Steve',start_date='2015-11-20';
```

Another thing to consider would be [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

Comment: I appreciate it. I ended up writing a else if statement for if value is true in record #. Got it going last night but I appreciate this.

Comment: View what I posted as answer that worked out for me @NextLocal

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing another if statement to check if a unique value existed from incoming and the existing db value existed and leaving it blank to prevent it from importing duplicates. I also wrote a separate file to update where values differentiate between what I am receiving as (new) and what is in the database (old) which actually worked out great for my application.

Here is my answer for anyone else that runs into this issue :)

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_keys=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$varvalues);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('');

            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) { 
                echo 'shits broke'; }
            }
        } 
        else { if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
                                            INSERT INTO table (column_keys)
                                            VALUES (?)")) // you will need a ? per column seperate by a , (?,?,?...?)

            { $insert_stmt->bind_param('s',
                                    $varvalues
                                    ); // you will also need to bind a 's' (string) 'i' for num, etc per $var value.

        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) { echo 'shits broke';} //lol 
            }
    }
    }
```

Also a simple error reporting trick I stumbled upon that helped me clean up a few things I overlooked. Just place it at the top of the file, or above you want to debug ;)

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`